# GET PROCESSING OPTION error with contactless Card

Tags: contactless-smartcard, emv

I'm trying to make the call `GET PROCESSING OPTION` regardless EMV Contactless.

The data is:

```
6F 42 84 07 A0 00 00 00 04 10 10 A5 37 50 0A 4D 61 73 74 65 72 43 61
72 64 87 01 01 5F 2D 08 69 74 65 6E 66 72 64 65 BF 0C 1A 9F 4D 02 0B
0A 9F 6E 07 03 80 00 00 30 30 00 9F 0A 08 00 01 05 04 00 00 00 00
```

PDOL is not present. So the GPO call is:

```
80A8000002830000
```

But I get the status **6985**. What mistake am I making?

Comment: This is not really a programming question. The response might be just the result of security/risk management options set in the card application. It might be just that ATC is over the limit.

Comment: So why the same call with the same data is succesful with chip card reading?

Comment: That may be happening if your app is disabled for contactless use. Impossible to say without looking at your card profile.